# trying to order by phone by orderByChild() but it is not working?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I don't know why but orderByChild() is Firebase database.

```
loadOrders(Common.currentUser.getPhone());
}

 private void loadOrders(final String phone) {

   FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Request> options;
   options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Request>()
           .setQuery(requests, Request.class)
           .build();
   Log.e(TAG, "after options");


   adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(options) {
       @Override
       protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Request model) {
           requests.orderByValue().equalTo(phone);
           holder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
           holder.txtOrderStatus.setText(convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
           holder.txtOrderAddress.setText(model.getAddress());
           holder.txtOrderPhone.setText(model.getPhone());
           final Request clickItem = model;
       }

       @NonNull
       @Override
       public OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
           View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.order_layout, parent, false);
           return new OrderViewHolder(view);
       }
       };
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   adapter.startListening();
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

here I'm trying to order Request by phone but data is not ordering, it is showing all the requests, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Request> options;
options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Request>()
       .setQuery(requests.orderByChild("phone"), Request.class)
       .build();
```

You'll also want to remove `requests.orderByValue().equalTo(phone)`, which is a meaningless statement here.

Comment: What is `requests` initialized to?

Comment: request is initialized to the database reference of requests node in firebase.

Comment: Please include the code that initializes it into your question. I'm quite sure the change I showed make the requests show up ordered by phone number, so the problem must be elsewhere in the code or in the expectation of what the database does.